# Switching between film and digital during the same shoot

Tags: film

If in digital shoot and I adjust my settings to the same thing that I am going to shoot with film, so for example ISO 400, strobe power xyz,etc.and shoot it with digital first, then can I confidently switch cameras and shoot the same thing on film? or still there are smaller nuances ? So idea is first I shoot it in digital, once it looks good than I shoot it with the same settings on film

Comment: Related and highly applicable: [Why are these film photos brighter than digital photos taken at the same time with the same settings?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79524/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be OK. Before the digital era, we did the same type of switcheroo. We loaded Polaroid film, made test shots, when satisfied; we loaded film and took the shots. This was especially helpful when slide film was called for because this material has low tolerance for color and exposure error.

Just keep in mind, the digital camera can have lots of tricks up its sleeve that might sneak in and apply some corrections and enhancements. What I am saying is, if the digital shots are to serve as benchmarks, be sure you turn off as much automation as possible.

Comment: oh great, you have used Polaroid backs hen ? Yes I actually ordered a polarodi back to use with Fuji-FP 100 ... so now even then the ISO of Fuji is 100 but if let's say ILLFORD is 400 then I should adjust the strobe powers for that

Comment: 2 Brandon -- The difference between 100 and 400 ISO is two f-stops. Thus if you load 100 ISO and the images look OK, then switch to 400, you must stop down 2 f-stops. Another approach is to turn the strobes down to 1/4 power. Another approach is to mount a 2 stop ND filter. A polarizer will work.  Another approach is to back the flash units up. Measure flash to subject distance and multiply distance by 1.4 for 1 stop reduction, by 2 for 2 stop reduction by 2.8 for 3 stop reduction. Likely studio not big enough so best to use flash at 1/4 power.

Comment: LOL because I LOVE Polaroid, Probably what I will end up doing is: First take it with digital, then take it with polaroid, then take it with film :D