# Are Negatives affected when a lab does color correction?

Tags: prints

The lab offered to colour correct my photos when they processed the film.  Unfortunately the colour correction was terrible compared to the same shot taken as a backup with an digital camera.  The backgrounds are over exposed and have a haze.  Is the colour correction done before the negatives are produced, or can I get another print from the negatives it they have not been altered somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally color correction today is done while processing the digital file after the negative is scanned but before the scanned file is printed. If the lab is still using analog enlargers, color correction is done using color filters between the enlarger's light and the negative. In either case, it does not affect the developed negative.

That does not guarantee, though, that the "pure" negatives will match the results from your digital camera. They almost certainly will not. There are a variety of issues, in terms of storing and handling film, exposing it, and developing it that could result in less than ideally developed negatives.

Even if the film was ideally exposed, it would still be different than a digital image of the same scene, just because [the way film and digital sensors respond to light can be different](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79524/15871).

Color film can only be properly balanced for one temperature and tint of light. If your film was shot under any other condition than the ideal light for your particular film, it needs to be color corrected.

If you are unhappy with the results from the lab, your first step might be to request they print the photos again and describe to them what you find unacceptable about the first set of prints.

Comment: Good answer. It's important to realise that a film photo will surely never match a digital photo exactly, because each film stock will have its own palette, just as different digital camera brands produce different colours. Fujifilm has some film "presets" that can be set in their digital cameras, to emulate some traditional film stocks, but even these will probably never be an exact match. As your link indicates, digital and film are just different. (And that's a good thing.)

Comment: That is good to know how the process works, so I will take your advice regarding the reprinting and talking to them about the overexposure and will see what results I get second time around - much appreciated guys!

Comment: A physical inspection of the negatives will tell you a lot about what the source of the issue is. It may be that the film was slightly fogged at some point, either before or after it was shot. There are other possibilities that could have occurred independently of the labs development process. Or the lab could have had issues when developing it. It's *really* hard to say without seeing a sample included in the question.